# How can i do a whereIn query in ElasticSearch?

Tags: php, elasticsearch

My Index looks like this

```
{name : 'John Doe',group_id : '1'},
{ name : 'Jane Doe', group_id : '2'}
{ name : 'John Doe', group_id : '3'}
```

and i want to return all indexes that its group_id is in this array [1, 2]

thus it would return:

```
{name : 'John Doe',group_id : '1'},
{ name : 'Jane Doe', group_id : '2'}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Terms Query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-query.html) for this. Replace `<index>` with the name of the index and `<type>` with the type you want to search on.

```
POST <index>/<type>/_search
{
   "query": {
      "terms": {
         "group_id": [
            "1",
            "2"
         ]
      }
   }
}
```